# Xcode Deployment Target Settings

Tags: xcode, deployment, release, target, deployment-target

1. If I want my app to be compatible with older OS versions, back to
   Snow Leopard, are these the proper deployment target settings in
   XCode?

   OS X Deployment Target under "Project": **10.8**

   Deployment Target under "Targets": **10.6**
2. What is the purpose of "OS X Deployment Target", if you can just use "Deployment Target"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have would probably work, but to be safe you should set the deployment target for both the project and target to 10.6 if you want your app to be compatible with Snow Leopard.

If your project has only one target, the OS X Deployment Target setting isn't all that helpful. The OS X Deployment Target setting can help for projects with multiple targets. You could set a base deployment target for the project with the OS X Deployment Target setting and use the target's Deployment Target setting to change the deployment target for a single target.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me understand when I would want more than one target? Wouldn't I just detect the OS version in my code and adjust accordingly, rather than making multiple targets?

Comment: Some situations where a project would have multiple targets include unit testing, having separate iPhone and iPad versions of an iOS app, and having a framework and an application in one project. Many projects don't need multiple targets, but multiple targets are available for those who need them.